# The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer - but application running on the same computer

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to debug an application but every time I do it reports it is unable to start debugging as the debugger cannot connect to the remote computer.

Only thing is the application it is debugging is a console application and there is no need to access a remote PC.

Answer (score 1):

In the Debug Section of the Project Properties the Use Remote Machine checkbox was clicked (why I don't rightly know) - for this reason it was trying to connect to a remote machine which just did not exist.

Clearing this flag got rid of the issue.

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Under Project Properties > Web section, I changed Project Url from some url that mapped to remote server to http://localhost/somePath, and it worked just fine.